# Loading string array from file

Tags: octave

How can I load a string array in Octave from a `csv` or `txt` file? The file has the format seen below. When using

```matlab
dlmread("TimeData.csv", ",")
```

it results in useless data like `2019 - 11i`.

```
`TIME`
    2019-11-08-13.27.03 +0100
    2019-11-08-13.27.08 +0100
    2019-11-08-13.27.13 +0100
    2019-11-08-13.27.18 +0100
    2019-11-08-13.27.23 +0100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [`dlmread`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/dlmread.html) (emphasis by me):

> Read **numeric** data from the text file *file* which uses the delimiter *sep* between data values.

Use [`textscan`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/textscan.html) instead (depending on your OS, the delimiter might needs to be modified):

```matlab
fid = fopen('TimeData.csv');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n')
fclose(fid);
```

Output:

```
C =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 2019-11-08-13.27.03 +0100
    [2,1] = 2019-11-08-13.27.08 +0100
    [3,1] = 2019-11-08-13.27.13 +0100
    [4,1] = 2019-11-08-13.27.18 +0100
    [5,1] = 2019-11-08-13.27.23 +0100
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to textscan, except it preserves empty lines.

```
function [textLines] = readFile (file_in_dir)
    if nargin != 1 || isempty(file_in_dir)
        return
    end

    if exist(file_in_dir, "file")
        fid = fopen(file_in_dir, "r");
        data = char(fread(fid));
        fclose(fid);

        if !strcmp(data(end), "\n")
            data = [data ; "\n"];
        end

        data(data == "\r") = [];
        newlines = [0, [1 : rows(data)](data' == "\n")];

        textLines = cell(1, columns(newlines) - 1);
        for i = 1 : columns(newlines) - 1
            textLines{i} = data(newlines(i) + 1 : newlines(i + 1) - 1)';
        end
    else
        textLines = {};
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for ugly `textscan` shenanigans.

Just use the [`csv2cell`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/function/csv2cell.html) function from the [`io`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/index.html) package.
I've used it many times, works like a charm.